# mysql: select last 10 rows from DESC LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql

i'm working on a block which will display last 10 posts, when user clicks on "load more" button i would like to display 10 older posts.

how can i select last 10 rows if i'm already using DESC LIMIT?

```
mysql_query("SELECT title,id,alt_name FROM dle_post WHERE approve='1' AND date >= '$monthagodate'
AND date < '$curdate' + INTERVAL 1 day ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $more;");
```

Comment: what is not working about what you're doing? What error are you seeing? It should work perfectly fine to parameterize more and just re-render the posts....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are LIMITing using just one parameter. But you can use `LIMIT x,y` to specify both `x` (the position of the first record to return) and `y` (the number of records to return).

Pass a variable to the page like `results.php?start=x` to set a starting position.

```
if (!isset( $_REQUEST['start'] ) ) { $start = 0; } else { $start = (int)$_REQUEST['start']; }

mysql_query("SELECT title,id,alt_name FROM dle_post WHERE approve='1' AND date >= '$monthagodate'
AND date < '$curdate' + INTERVAL 1 day ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $start,10;");
```

And then you can generate a link to the next page like so:

`echo '<a href="results.php?start=' . ($_REQUEST['start']+10) . '">Next 10 results</a>';`

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in linking to next results page, we should use the `$start` variable we populate at the top of the code (instead of `$_REQUEST['start']`) like so: `... . ($start+10) . ...`. The reason being that if the user comes to the page without passing the start variable in the URL, it will generate a warning level error for trying to access undefined index `start` in `$_REQUEST` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should add another parameter `$start` and use the following query

```
mysql_query("SELECT title,id,alt_name FROM dle_post WHERE approve='1' AND date >= '$monthagodate' AND date < '$curdate' + INTERVAL 1 day ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $start, $more;");
```

Here `$start` is used to tel `MySQL` the starting point of records to be fetched.